# What would be the equivalent of java enum in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enums in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby)

How do you declare something like

```
public enum fruit {
    mango ("mango", 1),
    banana ("banana", 2),
    apple ("apple", 3)

    private fruit(String name, int index) {
        ....
    }
}
```

I would like to show the strings in the user interface, but would like to store the integers in the database.

Comment: Have you looked here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby.

Comment: When you are using enums with database you basically separating your data to two sources. I think it's much better to introduce another db table to store these values.