# Ruby "Enum" Comparison

Tags: ruby

Of course enum's don't exist in Ruby, but based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby) I've used something like the following:

```
class PostType
   Page = 1,
   Post = 2
end
```

I want to pass the value to a method and use it for a comparison. So:

```
initialize(post_type)
   if post_type = PostType::Page
       # do something here
   elsif post_type = PostType::Post
       # do something else here
   end
end
```

But this doesn't work, regardless of what I pass into the constructor of my class, it always yields the same result.

Any ideas as to why passing the "fake enum" into a method and trying to compare it won't work? Do I have to compare the value? i.e. `post_type = 2` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you assign instead of compare

```
initialize(post_type) 
   if post_type == PostType::Page 
       # do something here 
   elsif post_type == PostType::Post 
       # do something else here 
   end 
end
```

Comment: Dang, there's me thinking Ruby syntax for comparisons were single ='s. Stupid mistake. Cheers!

Comment: If you use "ruby -w", you'd get a warning for using an assignment in a conditional expression. Better than nothing I suppose?

Comment: you'r right but i don't us the -w myself much cause my results and the real errors tend to get obfuscated by them, often it are remarks about deprecated things in gems which you don't control

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact you should use `Symbol`s, there's a syntax error, I assume you want different semantics:

```
if post_type = PostType::Page
```

should be

```
if post_type == PostType::Page
```

So your code should look like

```
if post_type == :page
...
```

Comment: Because it's the ruby way. If you code in ruby, use the ruby mindset, not one where you use magic numbers.

Comment: Alright, but although it's right, I see it as not rather unrelated to the original question. But ultimately I +1 based on the fact your argument boils down to "you cannot achieve the type-safety you'd get from Enums in Java (for example) in ruby.

Comment: type-safety you have in java, all the rest of the goodies in ruby 8>), i remind the time i was programming in java to lose half of my time because i had to convert vars and methods to such or so type

Comment: Yes, it's unrelated. But I assume there's a slight culture of hinting people if they're about to shoot themselves in the foot. And no, it's not about type-safety. It's about embracing the style of the ruby community. If you see someone use strings as Enums in Java, you'll likely tell them they're doing it wrong as well.

Comment: +1 It is _not_ unrelated. Tass answered the question, _and_ suggested a better approach. I'm actually shocked; this is the only answer that mentions `Symbol`s, which is _specifically_ designed to solve the problem of naming things.

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning instead of comparing. Using `==` instead of `=` should yield better results.

```
 initialize(post_type)
    if post_type == PostType::Page
        # do something here
    elsif post_type == PostType::Post
        # do something else here
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `case`:

```
case post_type
  when PostType::Page then  # Do something
  when PostType::Post then  # Do something else
  else raise 'Invalid post type'
end
```

Also, you really should be using `Symbol`s for this:

```
case post_type
  when :page then # Do something
  when :post then # Do something else
  else raise 'Invalid post type'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That's why a good habit to do this:

```
def initialize(post_type)
   if PostType::Page == post_type
       # do something here
   elsif PostType::Post == post_type
       # do something else here
   end
end
```

If you do make such a mistake, the compiler will make a warning `"already initialized constant ..."`