# Swap hash keys with values and convert keys to symbols in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

This is the input hash:

```
p Score.periods #{"q1"=>0, "q2"=>1, "q3"=>2, "q4"=>3, "h1"=>4, "h2"=>5}
```

This is my current code to exchange the keys with the values, while converting the keys to symbols:

```
periods = Score.periods.inject({}) do |hsh,(k,v)|
  hsh[v] = k.to_sym
  hsh
end
```

Here is the result:

```
p periods #{0=>:q1, 1=>:q2, 2=>:q3, 3=>:q4, 4=>:h1, 5=>:h2}
```

It just seems like my code is clunky and it shouldn't take 4 lines to do what I'm doing here. Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Swapping keys and values in a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989259/swapping-keys-and-values-in-a-hash)

Comment: Not a dup, @Cupcake, a close cousin.  Here the keys are strings and are converted to values that are symbols.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Hash[periods.values.zip(periods.keys.map(&:to_sym))]
```

Or if you're using a version of Ruby where [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) is available for arrays, you can do this:

```
periods.values.zip(periods.keys.map(&:to_sym)).to_h
```

What the two examples above do is make arrays of the keys and values of the original hash. Note that the string keys of the hash are mapped to symbols by passing `to_sym` to `map` as a `Proc`:

```
periods.keys.map(&:to_sym)
# => [:q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :h1, :h2]

periods.values
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then it zips them up into an array of `[value, key]` pairs, where each corresponding elements of `values` is matched with its corresponding key in `keys`:

```
periods.values.zip(periods.keys.map(&:to_sym))
# => [[0, :q1], [1, :q2], [2, :q3], [3, :q4], [4, :h1], [5, :h2]]
```

Then that array can be converted back into a hash using `Hash[array]` or `array.to_h`.

Comment: nice.  i have a to_sym function in there too, so i think it has to be this, Score.periods.values.zip(Score.periods.keys.map{|k| k.to_sym}).to_h

Comment: @appleLover I made it even shorter than that, check it out.

Comment: @appleLover is `Score` an Active Record relation from Ruby on Rails? If it is, be careful not to query the database more than once when calling `Score.periods` twice like that. I'm not sure if it's actually going to be queried twice in your case, just something you might want to double check that you're not doing.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is:

```
data = {"q1"=>0, "q2"=>1, "q3"=>2, "q4"=>3, "h1"=>4, "h2"=>5}

Hash[data.invert.collect { |k, v| [ k, v.to_sym ] }]
```

The `Hash[]` method converts an array of key/value pairs into an actual Hash. Quite handy for situations like this.

If you're using Ruby on Rails this could be even easier:

```
data.symbolize_keys.invert
```

Comment: You should be able to use `to_h` instead of `Hash[]` depending on your version of Ruby, right?

Comment: That was added in Ruby 2.1 I believe, so yeah, there is that option as well.

Comment: You could skip `invert`: `Hash[data.collect { |k, v| [ v, k.to_sym] }]`.

Comment: It occurred to me that my comment applies to my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {"q1"=>0, "q2"=>1, "q3"=>2, "q4"=>3, "h1"=>4, "h2"=>5}

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[v] = k.to_sym  }
  #=> {0=>:q1, 1=>:q2, 2=>:q3, 3=>:q4, 4=>:h1, 5=>:h2}
```

The steps are as follows (for the benefit of Ruby newbies).

```
enum = h.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {0=>"q1", 1=>"q2", 2=>"q3", 3=>"q4",
  #                  4=>"h1", 5=>"h2"}:each_with_object({})>
```

The elements that will be generated by the enumerator and passed to the block can be seen by converting the enumerator to an array, using [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) or [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

```
enum.entries
  #=> [[["q1", 0], {}], [["q2", 1], {}], [["q3", 2], {}],
  #    [["q4", 3], {}], [["h1", 4], {}], [["h2", 5], {}]]
```

Continuing,

```
enum.each { |(k,v),g| g[v] = k.to_sym  }
  #=> {0=>:q1, 1=>:q2, 2=>:q3, 3=>:q4, 4=>:h1, 5=>:h2}
```

In the last step, [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) passes the first element generated by `enum` to the block and assigns the three block variables. Consider the first element of `enum` that is passed to the block and the associated calculation of values for the three block variables. (I must first execute `enum.rewind` to reinitialize `enum`, as `each` above took the enumerator to its end. See [Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind)).

```
(k, v), g = enum.next
  #=> [["q1", 0], {}]
k #=> "q1"
v #=> 0
g #=> {}
```

See [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). The block calculation is therefore

```
g[v] = k.to_sym
  #=> :q1
```

Hence,

```
g #=> {0=>:q1}
```

The next element of `enum` is passed to the block and similar calculations are performed.

```
(k, v), g = enum.next
  #=> [["q2", 1], {0=>:q1}] 
k #=> "q2" 
v #=> 1 
g #=> {0=>:q1} 
g[v] = k.to_sym
  #=> :q2 
g #=> {0=>:q1, 1=>:q2}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.