# Return maximum of 2D Array

Tags: ruby

I have a 2D array:

```
[["user1", 20], ["user2", 30], ["user3", 10]]
```

The first element of a subarray is the *username*, and the second one its *score*.

I need to return the username with the maximum score. For example, here it would return `"user2"`.

Either one user has a higher score, or they all have the same score (in which case it should return `"all"`).

I know how to do this with a bunch of iterations and many lines of code, but I'm trying to find the "best practice way".

What would you advise ?

Comment: What's a `user` in this context - `["user1", 20]` or `"user1"`? And is a user's number the number within the string (i.e. `1` in `"user1"`) or the second element (i.e. `20` in  `["user1", 20]`)? That being said, I would advice to use a custom `User` class with attributes `:name` and `:number` or at least a hash instead of an array.

Comment: the first element of a subarray is the username, and the second one its score. The number is the second element of the subarray.

Comment: Maybe because the question was unclear or because you didn't include your own attempt.

Comment: What the expected result if there is more than one maximum score?

Comment: @Stefan thanks, edited it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

```
users = [["user1", 20], ["user2", 30], ["user3", 10]]

users.max_by{ |user, weight| weight }
#=> ["user2", 30]

# shorthand
users.max_by(&:last)
#=> ["user2", 30]

users.max_by(&:last).first
#=> "user2"
```

It worth to be mentioned that if you have a number of maximums it will return only first one.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for the given example:

```
a = [["user1", 20], ["user2", 30], ["user3", 10]]
h = Hash[a].invert
h[h.keys.max]
#=> "user2"
```

In the general case, where identical maximum numbers will occur, the following solution will return all users sharing the same maximum value (w/ invert function by Nigel, see [Swapping keys and values in a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989259/swapping-keys-and-values-in-a-hash)):

```
class Hash
  def safe_invert
    self.each_with_object( {} ) { |(key, value), out| ( out[value] ||= [] ) << key }
  end
end

a = [["user1", 20], ["user2", 30], ["user3", 10], ["user4", 30]]
h = Hash[a].safe_invert
h[h.keys.max]
#=> ["user2", "user4"]
```