# ruby understanding enum method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I was reading another SO question [Enums in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby) and it had the following code snippet:

```
class Enum

  private

  def self.enum_attr(name, num)
    name = name.to_s

    define_method(name + '?') do
      @attrs & num != 0
    end

    define_method(name + '=') do |set|
      if set
        @attrs |= num
      else
        @attrs &= ~num
      end
    end
  end

  public

  def initialize(attrs = 0)
    @attrs = attrs
  end

  def to_i
    @attrs
  end
end
```

As I understand this, this is defining a class method named `enum_attr`, is that correct? What I'm unsure of is what it means to have the `define_method` statements inside of the `enum_attr` method.

Then later on that post it shows the class being extended as follows

```
class FileAttributes < Enum
  enum_attr :readonly,       0x0001
  enum_attr :hidden,         0x0002
end
```

I don't quite understand what this second part does - can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Enum`, a method, `enum_attr`, is defined on the class's singleton, and is available to all subclasses. This method is in scope in the class definition body, and in `FileAttributes` it is being called with the arguments `:readonly, 0x0001` and then `:hidden, 0x0002`.

When `enum_attr` is called (let's look at just the first call, `enum_attr :readonly, 0x0001`), it defines two methods: `readonly?` & `readonly=(set)`. The result of this call to `enum_attr` is functionally equivalent to writing out the following in `FileAttributes`:

```
def readonly?
  @attrs & 0x0001 != 0
end

def readonly=(set)
  if set
    @attrs |= 0x0001
  else
    @attrs &= ~0x0001
  end
end
```

Since the block passed to `define_method` is a closure, the variable `num` from the scope in which the block is passed is still in scope when you call the method that is defined. In other words, the `num` variable passed in to `enum_attr` is still available within the generated methods `readonly?` & `readonly=` when they are called later from a different scope.

`define_method` must be used because the name of the method is being dynamically generated (i.e., we do not know the name of the method ahead of time).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So enum_attr :readonly, 0x0001 is just a method call with two parameters? If so, is that code just in the body of FileAttributes? Does it not need to be in a method block or in initialize?

Comment: If you're coming from a background in, say, Java, you might think so, but Ruby doesn't work that way. You can run any code you like in a `class` block. Inside a `class` block, `self` will be the class which is being defined, so any method calls without a receiver will go to the class object (in this case `FileAttributes`).

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. How can FileAttributes actually call enum_attr though if it is listed as private?

Comment: `private` methods can never be called with a receiver, so you can only call them on `self`. In this case, `self` is `FileAttributes`, just as  it is inside a call to a class method on `FileAttributes`.

Comment: @JeffStorey `private` in Ruby is not the same as `private` is some other languages. Private methods in Ruby can be accessed by subclasses.

Comment: I reread that section of pickaxe, thanks. As I now seem to understand it, subclasses can call their own instance's private methods, whereas with protected methods, a subclass can call any instance's (of that type) protected methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a class method which generates true/false attributes which are stored using a bitfield. Do you have a background in C (or perhaps Java)? If so, you may be familiar with bitfields and general "bit twiddling". Most Internet resources on these topics will be related to C; but you can still use them in Ruby and other languages.

In this case, you don't gain anything from storing your boolean attributes in individual bits, and I would advise you not to actually use this code. You would be better off using a different instance variable for each attribute, with `true` or `false` values.

Comment: thanks. I am familiar with bid twiddling. I wasn't actually trying to use this code, but I'm learning ruby and I'm trying to understand the code more than anything.

Comment: OK. There are some very important concepts for you to take from this code: that classes in Ruby are also objects, and you can call methods on them; that there is nothing "special" about class and method definitions in Ruby (they are just code which is executed like any other code); also, if you're not familiar with closures, this is a good introduction for you. To understand Ruby, you *need* to "get" closures, so make sure you understand what is going on there.

Comment: Yep, I have a groovy/Java background, so I use closured quite frequently in groovy. I'm finding a lot of the code concepts in ruby easy to understand because I've done a lot of groovy work.