# Alternative to create a table when number of Category instances is fixed/limited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app will only have three instances of the model `Category` - "Published", "Draft", "Unpublished".

Instinctively it feels redundant to create a table for this.

I'm thinking of storing the three category titles in a `Constant` instead, but I don't know where the best place is to put the `Constant` such that it can be referenced by multiple models.

Is there any better solution to this, or am I overthinking the issue all together (i.e. should I just create a "normal" model class/table)?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with it.

Comment: "Just" referencing to them from other models, as if they would have ID keys.

Comment: Don't you use them in queries (joins, etc.)?

Comment: Yea, you're right. After some consideration I'll go with a ActiveRecord::Base class. I'd need all ORM benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initializer file would be best suited to define those constants. Better yet, use [configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron).

Answer (score 1):

You need an enum. But Ruby doesn't have enums - so see this instead - [Enums in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby)