# In ruby, where do you put related symbols like enum in java?

Tags: ruby, enums, symbols

As I understand from [Enums in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby) question, you use `Symbols` to stand for something in ruby instead of `enums` in other languages as java or C#.

When you have enums, you can gather related identifiers in one place as below. You can see from the code that there are three colors available, and that `paint` method accepts one of those three values.

```
enum Color {
  Red,
  Yellow,
  Purple
}
public void paint(Color color) {}
```

how do you document the available values for related symbols in ruby?(`:red`, `:yellow`, `:purple`) Do you have to put it in a comment in the method that uses them, as below?

```
# allowed colors: :red, :yellow, :purple
def paint(color)
end
```

Comment: My personal preference is to make a module that just contains constant values. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/76046/3124288

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enums in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby)

Comment: @JKillian so you use `constants` instead of `symbols`?

Comment: Well, the constants can be a symbol, string, integer, Class, etc, not particularly important. The Enums in Ruby question has lots of good answers though that give you different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I create a constant array containing the allowed symbols. You can freeze it if you want to be sure that it won't change.

```
COLORS = [:red, :green, :blue].freeze
```

If you have a lot of different elements, you can use the `%i()` syntax:

```
COLORS = %i(red green blue yellow purple).freeze
```

And if you're using Rails, since the 4.1 version there's a [enum macro](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) available for ActiveRecord::Base.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum color: %i(red green blue yellow purple)
end

Car.new(color: :red)
```

Comment: in the `initialize` method of `Car`, do you validate that `color` is indeed in the `COLORS`, or is it just for documentation purposes?

Comment: If you try to pass an invalid element, Rails will raise an error: `Car.new(color: :small)` throws an `ArgumentError: 'small' is not a valid color` error. By the way, Rails allows you to pass a string as well, and it'll convert it to the correct value. Internally, an enum is represented as an integer column in the database.

Comment: Oh sorry, now I've seen that I forgot to write the inheritance, gonna fix that.

Comment: how do I actually use the constant array, for example if I want to check if a variable is `:red` or if I want to pass in a value of `:red`?

Answer (score 2):

```
module TOKEN_TYPES 

  def self.const_missing(name)
    type = TYPES.find { |e| e == name.to_s.upcase.to_sym }
                    raise "constant not found error" if type.nil?
  return type

  end

# punctuation
TYPES = [:LEFT_PAREN, :RIGHT_PAREN, :LEFT_BRACE, :RIGHT_BRACE,
       :COMMA, :DOT, :SEMICOLON, :SLASH, :BACK_SLASH, :STAR,

# mathematical operators
:OP_PLUS, :OP_MINUS, :OP_MUL, :OP_DIV, :LT, :LE, :EQ, :NE, :GT, :GE, :OP_POW, # ne = <>

# logical operators
:TRUE, :FALSE, :NIL,

# program flow

# errors

# other
:AMPERSAND,

# literals
:NUM, :STRING, :SYM, :IDENTIFIER, :CONSTANT,

# keywords
:CLASS, :MODULE, :BEGIN, :END, :IF, :ELSE, :IF, :UNLESS, :DO, :WHILE, :FOR, :UNTIL,
:NEXT, :SKIP, :BREAK, :RETURN, :DEF, :ENFORCE, :INCLUDE, :EXTEND,

:EOF]
end
```

This may not suit everybody's needs. I just wanted symbols without value.
You can use it like this

```
type = TOKEN_TYPES::CLASS
# => type = :CLASS
```